# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when retrieving views from transition context on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have the following code, which works perfectly on my iPhone 5 and all the iPhone simulators, but it crashes on my iPhone 4.  I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the last line where I pass UITransitionContextToViewKey to my transition context.

I have a clean analyze and build, and the same happens for both UITransitionContextFromViewKey and UITransitionContextToViewKey.

My iPhone 4 is on iOS 7.1.2, my deployment target is 7.0, targeted build base SDK 8.0.

Anyone knows what to do here?  thx.

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    // get transition parameters from context
    UIView *containerView = transitionContext.containerView;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController =
    [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    if ([destinationViewController.title isEqualToString:@"ListController"]) {

        // get source and destination views
        UIView *sourceViewSnapshot = [self.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];

        UIView *destinationView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS

// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/UIViewControllerContextTransitioning_protocol/index.html):

> UITransitionContextToViewKey
>
> **Available in iOS 8.0 and later.**

You can't run that code on iOS 7

You might want to add runtime system version checks and branch out to a iOS 7 compatible code at this point if you want to maintain compatibility with this version of the system

Comment: omg.. how do u handle custom transitioning in iOS 7 then?  - never mind I'll figure something out.  thanks.

Comment: @believesInSanta Take a look at this: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html

Answer (score 6):

The viewForKey method is iOS 8 and up, but the viewControllerForKey method is supported in iOS 7. A small change to your code gets the view in iOS 7:

```
   UIView *destinationView = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey].view;
```

Comment: good to know; will save it for next time i have to deal with it